# how to make the section header float in UITableView ..

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make the section headers of the UITableView float i.e. the section headers should be visible as long as the rows of the sections are visible.

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is behavior you get for free with a plain style UITableView.  Are you using a grouped style UITableView?

Comment: @Paul : Yes, I am  using a grouped style UITableView, can it be done there too ? Also, do I need to set anything to get this behaviour with the plain style ? Thanks.

Comment: This behavior is not supported with the grouped style of UITableView.  You do not need to set anything to attain this with the plain style as far as I can remember.  Are you not seeing it with a plain style UITableView?

Comment: @Paul : thanks for the hint. yeah, it works nicely. thanks a bunch !

Comment: @ahsan you should delete the question if it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your *UITableView*'s style to **UITableViewStylePlain**.

You could do this either from the StoryBoard / NIB or via code.

Floating section headers are the default style of UITableView (plain) in iOS.